# Choose from list?

Tags: applescript

Can someone tell me why this won't work? I can't for the life of me figure out why it doesn't. It compiles fine, looks fine, and this method has worked everywhere else for me... Really need some help, anyone know what's wrong?

```
set areatype to (choose from list {"Triagles", "Trapeziums"} with prompt "What would you like to calculate the area of?" with title "Area Calculator")

if areatype contains "Triangles" then

    set height to text returned of (display dialog "What is the height of the triangle?" with title "Area Calculator" default answer "")

    set base to text returned of (display dialog "What is the base of the triangle?" with title "Area Calculator" default answer "")

    set area to (height * base) / 2

    display dialog "Area = " & area & " units squared" with title "Area Calculator" buttons {"Cancel", "Go again"}

else

    if areatype contains "Trapezium" then

        set base1 to text returned of (display dialog "What is one base of the trapezium?" with title "Area Calculator" default answer "")

        set base2 to text returned of (display dialog "What is the other base of the trapezium?" with title "Area Calculator" default answer "")

        set area to ((a + b) / 2) * h
        display dialog "Area = " & area & " units squared" with title "Area Calculator" buttons {"Cancel", "Go again"}


    end if
end if
```

-Thanks

Comment: It's really helpful in these sorts of questions if you show some effort. Try commenting out your entire code, then adding it back in, line by line, and see what happens. You should find your answer pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your very first line in the code.  You spelled Triangles incorrectly  and you needed the "s" in Trapeziums added to the "else" line in the code.

```
on goAgain()

    set areatype to (choose from list {"Triangles", "Trapeziums"} with prompt "What would you like to calculate the area of?" with title "Area Calculator")

    if areatype contains "Triangles" then
        set height to text returned of (display dialog "What is the height of the triangle?" with title "Area Calculator" default answer "")
        set base to text returned of (display dialog "What is the base of the triangle?" with title "Area Calculator" default answer "")
        set area to (height * base) / 2

        display dialog "Area = " & area & " units squared" with title "Area Calculator" buttons {"Cancel", "Go again"}

        if the button returned of the result is "Go again" then
            goAgain()
        else
            return
        end if

    else

        if areatype contains "Trapeziums" then
            set base1 to text returned of (display dialog "What is one base of the trapezium?" with title "Area Calculator" default answer "")
            set base2 to text returned of (display dialog "What is the other base of the trapezium?" with title "Area Calculator" default answer "")
            set height2 to text returned of (display dialog "What is the height of the trapezium?" with title "Area Calculator" default answer "")
            set area to ((base1 + base2) / 2) * height2

            display dialog "Area = " & area & " units squared" with title "Area Calculator" buttons {"Cancel", "Go again"}

            if the button returned of the result is "Go again" then
                goAgain()
            else
                return
            end if

        end if
    end if
end goAgain

goAgain()
```

Comment: That code should work correctly for you but all you need to do is configure the actions for the {"Cancel", "Go again"} buttons

Comment: Nevermind, I went ahead and fixed the {"Cancel", "Go again"} buttons for you

Comment: Ok thanks. I just cut out the button functions to try keep it short. Seems obvious now, sorry for wasting your time. Should've looked more closely.